# Refresh Database automatically

Tags: qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm a new user of QGIS. I have a problem trying to update layers from a database.
I have a MySQL database in a server that I add as a layer (or more than one, depends on the project) with no problem.
That database changes each five minutes, and I want to update the associate/s layer/s.
Now, I push the refresh buttom, but I guess that this could be done automatically, without my interference, as a programmed routine or plugin.
Any have tried it?
Do you know how to achieve it?
Thanks in advance!
Laura